i have problem with facebook api in postman
i test like facebook post request in graph facebook api. i use my access token and i have a post_id, this endpoint is:"http://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/likes". when i send this request then post have a post_id was liked. I did the same thing on postman (endpoint:https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{post_id}/likes) and passed in the parameter Authorization:{access_token} but it failed and returned 400 bad request:
"error": {
"message": "(#3) Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 3,
"fbtrace_id": "AU3wMLbb67rRXR4mgF-4FoX"
}
I hope that there is someone who has been like me and has solved this problem to share with me the documents to solve it.

"and passed in the parameter Authorization:{access_token}" - if you pass the access token as a request parameter, then the name needs to be access_token. If you are using an Authorization header, then the format needs to be Authorization: Bearer {access token}

It seems you're using a user access token to request API, but for actions like liking a post, you should use the access token associated with the page where the post is published.
You can obtain the access token for each page using the /me/accounts API endpoint. This endpoint will return details of all the pages belonging to your account with an access token, which you can then use when working with the post of the page.
